# using ros-tooling/action-ros-ci in a private repo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to use ros-tooling/action-ros-ci with a private repo. Here are the contents of .github/workflows/build_test.yml:

```
name: ROS CI
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  foxy_build:
    name: foxy_build
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      - uses: ros-tooling/setup-ros@0.3.2
        with:
          required-ros-distrutions: foxy
      - uses: ros-tooling/action-ros-ci@0.2.5
        with:
          package-name: gst_tools
          target-ros2-distro: foxy
```

IIUC, this should "just work" with a private repo. But I'm consistently getting github action errors like this:

```
Run ros-tooling/action-ros-ci@0.2.5
  with:
    package-name: gst_tools
    target-ros2-distro: foxy
    colcon-mixin-repository: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository/master/index.yaml
  env:
    LANG: en_US.UTF-8

Repos files: override - none
Repos files: supplemental - none
Invoking: bash -c,rosdep update --include-eol-distros
  /usr/bin/bash -c rosdep update --include-eol-distros
  reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
  Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
  Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
  Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
  Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
  Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
  Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
  Add distro "ardent"
  Add distro "bouncy"
  Add distro "crystal"
  Add distro "dashing"
  Add distro "eloquent"
  Add distro "foxy"
  Add distro "galactic"
  Add distro "groovy"
  Add distro "humble"
  Add distro "hydro"
  Add distro "indigo"
  Add distro "jade"
  Add distro "kinetic"
  Add distro "lunar"
  Add distro "melodic"
  Add distro "noetic"
  Add distro "rolling"
  updated cache in /home/runner/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
Invoking: bash -c,vcs diff -s --repos /home/runner/work/gst_tools/gst_tools/ros_ws | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep "gst_tools$" | xargs rm -rf
  /usr/bin/bash -c vcs diff -s --repos /home/runner/work/gst_tools/gst_tools/ros_ws | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep "gst_tools$" | xargs rm -rf
Invoking: bash -c,vcs import --force --recursive src/ < package.repo
  /usr/bin/bash -c vcs import --force --recursive src/ < package.repo
  === src/adkd07aag29/gst_tools (git) ===
  Could not clone repository 'https://github.com/clydemcqueen/gst_tools.git': Cloning into '.'...
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
Error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

In comparison, I have zero problems with creating a private repo using https://github.com/ros-tooling/action-ros-ci-template which uses tooling/action-ros2-lint rather than ros-tooling/action-ros-ci.

Any clues?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401686/using-ros-tooling/action-ros-ci-in-a-private-repo/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2022-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot to add the `import-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` argument in the call to `action-ros-ci`. This works:

```
name: ROS CI
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  foxy_build:
    name: foxy_build
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      - uses: ros-tooling/setup-ros@0.3.2
        with:
          required-ros-distrutions: foxy
      - uses: ros-tooling/action-ros-ci@0.2.5
        with:
          package-name: gst_tools
          target-ros2-distro: foxy
          import-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This is in the README, but I missed it. There is a [good discussion in the PR](https://github.com/ros-tooling/action-ros-ci/pull/692).

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2